# Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad E470

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, hardware-certification

I'm considering to buy a Lenovo ThinkPad E470 which I most likely will run Ubuntu 16.04 on. Is this machine "plug and play" with Ubuntu 16.04, or does it require any kind of configuration adventures? I do see that it has been certified for Ubuntu, but I'd like to hear if anyone has hands on experience with this machine.

**Specs**

- i5-7200U
- Intel HD Graphics 620

**Questions**

1. The [Ubuntu Hardware Certification](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201609-25122/) site mentions Hibernation as not working. Anyone got experience with this?
2. If you plugin in a HDMI cable for an external monitor, can you then close the LID and use the external monitor only? I've had numerous battles with Ubuntu going into hibernation when closing the lid, regardless of battery/hibernation settings.
3. Does wireless and cabled network work out of the box?

Comment: I ended up buying a Dell Latitude E7480 with i5 and Intel graphics. Everything works out of the box with Ubuntu 16.04. Not a single issue with external monitor via HDMI, hibernation or networking. W

Answer (score 4):

I'm writting this using an E470 running 16.04.3 LTS, so

1. No hibernation option. Suspend works like a charm.
2. <s>No idea.</s> This is by default on KDE (I'm using Neon 5.8.7)
3. wifi (and graphics) worked OOTB, but anyway if you have any problem you can use this tool to upgrade the drivers https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2 2.0.2 is the last version that works with Ubuntu 16.04. Cabled network is too from 1990 for me :P

**Edit**: just realized that, at least with linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge              4.13.0.16.23, this is no longer needed:

> The thing that annoyed me the most is that trackpoint middle button is
>   not detected OOTB, so no scroll either. This package fixes it
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04/+bug/1670492/comments/12

Answer (score 3):

Unforunately the E470 model doesn't support Ubuntu 17.04 too. I mean it doesn't have Wifi Device drivers in the standard Ubuntu image like the certification site says. Only the Wired network works.